Bash − Using one bc instance in a named pipe
Context: I have a script which makes multiple calls to bc to set some values, ie: many foo="$(echo '1/3' | /usr/bin/bc -q)"
What I want to achieve: do not call bc every times, but keep one bc instance and re-use it multiple times.
I guess coproc may be what I need, but as I’m curious and want to understand how Bash works, I try to do it using named pipes.
This is my code so far, not the code of the script on which I intend to do this, but a code sample I wrote to try to help me understand what’s going on. It’s probably full of UUO* and questionable parts, but you’ll tell me then:
#!/bin/env -S -i bash --norc

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\t\n'

init_bc() {
    [[ -p /tmp/bci    ]] || mkfifo /tmp/bci
    [[ -p /tmp/bco    ]] || mkfifo /tmp/bco
    tail -n1 -f    >&/tmp/bci            &
    cat              /tmp/bco            &
    /usr/bin/bc -q   /tmp/bci >&/tmp/bco &
    echo "scale=50" >/tmp/bci
    wait &
}

do_bc() {
    echo "${1}" >/tmp/bci >&1
}

do_exit() {
    rm -vf /tmp/{bci,bco} >&2
    pkill -e -P $$
}

trap do_exit TERM EXIT INT
init_bc
echo Sleeping… >&2
foo="$(do_bc "${1}")"
echo "FOO: ${foo}"
sleep 5
echo "Awake!" >&2
wait &
echo "End of script. We wait for all sub-shells." >&2
wait


Running it (waiting a few seconds and then hitting Ctrl+C) this is what I get:
$ ./piped_bc '1/7'
Sleeping…
FOO: 
.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714
Awake!
End of script. We wait for all sub-shells.
^Cremoved '/tmp/bci'
removed '/tmp/bco'
 killed (pid 5585)
 killed (pid 5586)
 killed (pid 5587)


As you can see, the $foo variable doesn’t get valued, and this is what I do not understand.
The bc result seems to be “going” to the standard output, because if I run the script adding 1>/dev/null the result isn’t displayed, but I don’t understand why $foo is not valued then, and it upsets me (more than I’d like to admit).
Last thing which may be of interest for my question: If I do this in the terminal:
foo=$(/usr/bin/bc -q <(echo 'scale=7;1/7') &)

The variable $foo gets the result of 1/7 as expected:
$ echo $foo
.1428571

Why is it not in my script?
Any help would be, of course, greatly appreciated.

Have a look at Best way to divide and see how I use multiple parallelized bc to drawn a fractal at Is bash a programming language?

@f-hauri-give-up-github: I don’t think it answers my question :( I’ll try the “shell connector” part and see if it permits to value a variable, thank for the link…

Yes it does! Look in Best way to divide in bash using pipes?, just under Introducing shell connector, the sample show precisely what you're trying to do.

Yes, you damned right! Thx a lot. I wasn’t sure but it is obvious I have to rely on read too. Have a nice day.

Feel free to upvote Best way to divide in bash using pipes? if it answer you queston! ;-)
